# Kubernetes Resources Grouping vs Isolation with Namespace/s

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, monitoring, isolation

I always felt separating `k8s` resources with `namespace` is a good idea because:

1. It isolates the apps.
2. We can apply resource quotas for CPU or memory utilization.
3. Namespaces can help improve performance also.
4. RBAC/Network policy resources are locked into namespaces.
5. We can have better control over `k8s` resources.

etc. But recently I got into a discussion with my colleague regarding moving all the monitoring apps into a single namespace. And I know according to [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

> start using namespaces when you need the features they provide.

But separating `Prometheus`, `Vector` and `Grafana` etc. into separate `namespace` isn't a good idea from day 1 instead of waiting for them to conflict with others (e.g. consuming other app's resources).

Comment: I'd argue a namespace per application is probably good practice.  Namespaces do not particularly provide isolation of any sort, though, or improve performance at all; they are just a management tool.  Commands like `kubectl get` operate in a single namespace, for example, and a Pod can't include a Secret or PersistentVolumeClaim from another namespace.

Comment: According to this post: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-organizing-with-namespaces
You can have multiple namespaces inside a single Kubernetes cluster, and they are all logically isolated from each other. They can help you and your teams with organization, security, and even performance!